# How do I maintain position of a DragPanelExtender across postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, dom, asp.net-ajax

I already found this article:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=181&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

But I've got a different situation. I am embedding some hiddenFields inside of the master page and trying to store the position of the dragPanel in those.

I am using javascript to store the position of the dragPanel and then when the user clicks on a link, the new page is loaded, but the dragPanel is reset into the starting position.

**Is there any easy way to do this?**

Pseudocode:

```
**this is in MasterPage.master**


function pageLoad()

{  

    // call the savePanelPosition when the panel is moved

    $find('DragP1').add_move(savePanelPosition);  

    var elem = $get("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>");   

    if(elem.value != "0")
    {

        var temp = new Array();

        temp = elem.value.split(';');

        // set the position of the panel manually with the retrieve value

        $find('<%=Panel1_DragPanelExtender.BehaviorID%>').set_location(new 

Sys.UI.Point(parseInt(temp[0]),parseInt(temp[1])));

    }

}      


function savePanelPosition()

{
    var elem = $find('DragP1').get_element();

    var loc = $common.getLocation(elem);

    var elem1 = $get("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>");

    // store the value in the hidden field

    elem1.value = loc.x + ';' + loc.y;

}        


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="0"
```

However, **HiddenField** is not visible in the redirected page, foo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing the position information in a hidden field, store it in a cookie.  The information is small, so it will have minimal effect on the page load performance.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I got the drag stuff to work, saves in a database and all, brings up cool on my one monitor 1600X1050 all good, fine and dandy! BUT WAIT! I bring up the same page on my other monitor 1366x768 and the panels are all off.

The save function saves in pixels, so when you move over to another "resolution" the panels are off. ya know?

P.S. I could pop up a message stating the user to change their monitor settings, lol...